# Evaluating whether ComboBox.SelectedIndex is greater than -1 (no selection) in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I want to evaluate if a user has selected anything in a combobox so that I can magic up a new combobox below that. I read elsewhere that the `SelectedIndex` value `-1` is equivalent to the combobox being untouched by the user so I based my assumptions on this.

Here is my code:

```
function displayCarbs(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
            _categoryCarbs = new CategoryCarbs();
            addChild(_categoryCarbs);
            'positioning'
            _categoryCarbs.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _categoryCarbs.width / 2;
            _categoryCarbs.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - _categoryCarbs.height / 2;
            _categoryCarbs.btn_goback.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addNewIngredient)
            addChild(myComboBox);
            myComboBox.prompt="Choose your carbs";
            myComboBox.x= _ComboBoxXPosition;
            myComboBox.y = _ComboBoxYPosition;
            myComboBox.width = _ComboBoxWidth;
            myComboBox.height = _ComboBoxHeight;
            myComboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(myItems);
               trace("test1");
            if (myComboBox.selectedIndex > -1) {
                trace("test2");
                addChild(myComboBox);
                myComboBox.y = _ComboBoxYPosition + _SubsequentComboBoxIncrement;
                myComboBox.x = _ComboBoxXPosition;
                myComboBox.width = _ComboBoxWidth;
                myComboBox.height = _ComboBoxHeight;

            }
        }
```

Unfortunately my second trace doesn't reach the output window, and I can't think what's wrong with my `if` statement, or possibly I'm just being a bit thick!

Comment: Is `'positioning'` supposed to be a comment? `// positioning`

Comment: Seems like `myComboBox` lifecycle in convoluted in your example in terms of data provider, state, and being added to the display list.

Comment: @JasonSturges in what order should things appear? Unfortunately, even after replacing `myComboBox.selectedIndex > -1)` (my original logical test), with all of your suggestions, its not having the desired effect. When I used `== -1`, the `ComboBox` moved to it's "secondary position" (i.e. the `y` position were `_ComboBoxYPosition + _SubsequentComboBoxIncrement'.) Could this be something to do with the convolution you mention above?

Comment: There's likely multiple problems here.  In `displayCarbs()` function you add `myComboBox`, set the data provider, then test for a selected index in which you add the combo box again.  Make sure instances are in line with what you author via Flash Pro's artboard and code.

Comment: Is there not an easier way of replicating `myComboBox` programatically for `n` number of times based on whether it's predecessor's `selectedIndex` meets the conditions in my original question? (For example: let's say the maximum number of ComboBoxes allowed on the stage is 6)

Answer (score 0):

You're testing `myComboBox.selectedIndex` for less than -1.

Instead, test for any of the following:

- `selectedIndex == -1`
- `selectedIndex < 0`
- `selectedIndex <= -1`